# Извлечь регуляркой подстроку из URL'а

Tags: регулярные-выражения, dart

Есть URL следующего вида:

```
https://domain.ru/smth/smth_more/can_be_even_more_smth/3114-vopreki-vsemu-04-iz-16.html
```

В конце URL'а всегда есть строка вида

```
x-iz-y.html
```

, где `x,y` - некоторые некоторо-значные числа.

Необходимо с помощью регулярки извлечь отсюда подстроку

```
3114-vopreki-vsemu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берёте значение захваченной группы:

```
.+\/(.+)-\d+-iz-\d+\.html
```

Тест https://regexr.com/593d5

Ещё вариант, который просто находит нужный текст:

```
[^\/]+(?=-\d+-iz-\d+\.html)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/593d8

> https://domain.ru/smth/smth_more/can_be_even_more_smth/**3114-vopreki-vsemu**-04-iz-16.html
>
> https://domain.ru/smth/smth_more/can_be_even_more_smth/**xxxxx**-04-iz-04.html
>
> https://domain.ru/smth/smth_more/can_be_even_more_smth/**yyy**-55555-iz-1.html